# How can I get row names from the apply() function's output?

Tags: r, apply, tibble, r-rownames

I'm learning R and have a tibble with some World Bank data. I used the apply() function in a slice of the columns and applied the standard deviation over the values, in this way: `result <- apply(df[6:46],2,sd,na.rm=TRUE)`.

The result is an object with two columns with no header, one column is all the names of the tibble columns that were selected and the other one is the standard deviation for each column. When I use the typeof() command in the output, the result is `'double'`. The R documentation says the output of apply() is a vector, an array or a list.

I need to know this because I want to extract all the row names and using the command `rownames(result)` throws the output `NULL`. What can I do to extract the row names of this object?

[image]

Tried `rownames(result)` and `row.names(result` and none worked.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ronak Shah, your explanation cleared my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the `sd` returns a single value and as the `apply` is with `MARGIN = 2` i,e  columnwise, we are getting a named `vector`.  So, `names(out)` would get the `names` instead of `row.names`.  Using a reproducible example with the inbuilt dataset `iris`

```
data(iris)
out <- apply(iris[1:4], 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
names(out)
#[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

Also, by wrapping the output of `apply` with `data.frame`, we can use the `row.names`

```
out1 <- data.frame(val = out)
row.names(out1)
#[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

---

If we need a `data.frame` as output, this can he directly created with `data.frame` call

```
data.frame(names = names(out), values = out)
```

---

Also, this can be done in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
iris %>%
     summarise_if(is.numeric, sd, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
     gather
#     key     value
#1 Sepal.Length 0.8280661
#2  Sepal.Width 0.4358663
#3 Petal.Length 1.7652982
#4  Petal.Width 0.7622377
```

Or convert to a `list` and `enframe`

```
library(tibble)
iris %>%
    summarise_if(is.numeric, sd, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    as.list %>% 
    enframe
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `stack` to convert the vector output into dataframe.

```
temp <- stack(apply(df[6:46],2,sd,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Now, we can access all the column names with `temp$ind` and values of `sd` in `temp$values`.

Using `mtcars` as example,

```
temp <- stack(apply(mtcars, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE))
temp

#      values  ind
#1    6.02695  mpg
#2    1.78592  cyl
#3  123.93869 disp
#4   68.56287   hp
#5    0.53468 drat
#6    0.97846   wt
#7    1.78694 qsec
#8    0.50402   vs
#9    0.49899   am
#10   0.73780 gear
#11   1.61520 carb
```

We can also use this with `sapply` and `lapply`

```
stack(sapply(mtcars,sd, na.rm = TRUE))
#and
stack(lapply(mtcars,sd, na.rm = TRUE))
```